# CSS: sticky and scrollable element

Tags: html, css

I have HTML/CSS layout like here:

```
<div classname="container">
 <nav>  
   // some navigation elements
 </nav> 
  <div classname="wrapper">
    <div classname="list">
     <div classname="header">
      // some header elements
     </div>
     <div classname="list-element">
      Element 1
     </div>
     <div classname="list-element">
      Element 2
     </div>
     <div classname="list-element">
      Element 3
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.warpper {
 width: 500px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

.list {
 width: 800px;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}

.list-element {
 width: 100%
}
```

I want to make the "header" sticky, when the page is scrolling vertically. But at the same time, it should be scrollable horizontally with all content inside of "wrapper".

In other words, the header should stick to the top of the browser window during vertical scrolling, but it should be accessible for horizontal scrolling within the parent container at the same time.

My project is based on react/js, so you can use useref, usestate, useeffect, event listeners and other stuff.

Is it possible?